# Error using oracle.dataaccess.dll

Tags: .net, windows, oracle, 64-bit, odp.net

I have a web application which uses Oracle.DataAccess.dll to communicate with an Oracle db.
The web application deployed on 32 bit windows system works but not on windows server 2008 64 bit. I installed 10204_vista_win2k8_x64_production_db package, referenced the installed dll (version 2.102.4.0) from the project but I get the following error:

Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.102.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Answer (score 12):

Same here. The Oracle.DataAccess assembly doesn't run in 64 bit mode.

You should set the application pool for your site to 32 bit mode (go to the application pool's **Advanced Settings** and set **Allow 32 Bit Applications** to "True")

If that doesn't work, make sure your Oracle directory (the directory containing all the Oracle dlls) is in your system path. If you forget that, you get the same cryptic error about not finding Oracle.DataAccess.

**EDIT**:

Installing the Oracle client can be a major pain. Using the [Oracle Instant Client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html) is somewhat easier than installing the full client, so this is what I usually do:

1. Download the [Oracle Instant Client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html)
2. Unzip the archive in c:\oracle (any other directory will do)
3. Open a command prompt **as administrator**
4. type **cd \oracle**
5. type **configure odp.net20 myhome**
6. Right-click on "My Computer", "Advanced System Settings", "Environment Variables" and add the C:\oracle directory to the system path
7. Copy the Oracle.DataAccess.dll file from c:\oracle\odp.net\bin\2.x to your application's bin folder
8. (optonally) edit your c:\oracle\tnsnames.ora file

Comment: I set Enable 32 Bit Applications to true, but had no luck. I get the same error message.

What else can I do ?

Comment: Hi Leybaert,

What exactly do you mean by "make sure your Oracle directory (the directory containing all the Oracle dlls) is in your system path" ?
I installed ODAC 1020221 which installed the dlls to the following directory: e:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\ODP.NET\bin\. The weird thing is that the dlls don't get registered into the GAC by this install, so I referenced explicitly the dll from the project by its absolute path. Anyway, I get the same error message I mentioned in my previous post.
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: GRRRR.  What a lame set of error messages for such a simple change.  Turning on 32 bit applications resolved the issue for me.

Comment: " The Oracle.DataAccess assembly doesn't run in 64 bit mode" is not true anymore -- please see article 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29570523/implementing-oracle-web-dll-oracle-dataaccess-dll-64-bit-failed-on-windows-serv/29570524#29570524

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to give you the answers from what I've just went through on Windows Server 2008 R2 which is a 64 bit operating system.  The application suite of libraries I was given were developed using .net 3.5 x86 with the older DLL libraries and I was stuck because I had installed the newer x64 clients from oracle.

What I found was the following:
Install the latest x64 client from Oracle for Windows Server 2008.  I believe this would be the 2.7.0 client.  When you select the installation, make sure you do custom and select the .NET libraries.
Configure your tnsnames files and test your tnsping against your data source.

Next, if you are running a 32 bit application, install the same version of the client for 32 bit.  Also, follow the same installation routine, and select the same home.

When your finished, you will find that you have a single app/product with two client directories (Client1 and Client2).

if you navigate to the windows/assemblies directory you will find that you have a reference to the Oracle.DataAccess.dll (x2) with one for x86 and one for AMD64.

Now, depending on if you have developers or are developing on the machine yourself, you may be ok here, however, if they are using older drivers, then you need to perform one last step.

Navigate to the app\name\product\version\client_1\odp.net\publisher policy\2.x directory.  Included in here are two policy files.  use gacutil /i to install the Policy.2.111.Oracle.DataAccess.dll into the GAC.  This will redirect legacy oracle ODP calls to the newer versions.  So, if someone developed with the 10g client, it will now work with the 11 client.

If you need further details, or need other questions answered like flipping 32 bit mode on or off on your .net assemblies, email me.

J Banks
jbanks27@hotmail.com

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't have 32 bit oracle client working and installed 64 bit, you will need to install the 64 bit client, and grab the oracle.dataaccess.dll file under odp.net from the oracle client installed folder. And you have to use this dll and exchange the reference to this file instead of using 32 bit dll.( which is what you probably have for the project/solution)

If you have different bit of oracle client it's not going to work. so you will get errors like that.
Hope that helps.

See illustration on
[Implementing Oracle.Web.dll, Oracle.DataAccess.dll 64-bit failed on Windows Server 2008 with IIS 7.5 32-bit disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29570523/implementing-oracle-web-dll-oracle-dataaccess-dll-64-bit-failed-on-windows-serv/29570524#29570524)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the 32-bit version of Oracle.DataAccess.dll then you need to do one of the following:

a) Deploy to a 32-bit server, or

b) Deploy to a 64-bit server with 'Enable 32-bit applications' set to 'true'.

If you're using the 64-bit version of Oracle.DataAccess.dll then you simply have to use a 64-bit server.

The problem is caused by Oracle as the don't offer an AnyCPU version of Oracle.DataAccess.dll (probably because it has unmanaged/native portions)

Comment: So to get this to work (without compiler warnings) in Visual Studio 2012 / .NET 4.5 you'll need to set your dll reference "chain" that eventually references Oracle.DataAccess.dll to x86 or AMD64 (instead of AnyCPU) depending on if you are using the 32-bit or 64-bit version of the Oracle DLL, and then make sure you're deploying your app to a 32-bit/mode or 64-bit server

Comment: Or your other option is to ignore the warnings (and stay on AnyCPU) and then swap in/out between the 32-bit/64-bit versions of Oracle.DataAccess.dll depending on whether you're deploying your app to a 32-bit server/mode or 64-bit server.

Comment: "You have to change your project's target processor to one of these cpu's. Unfortunally Oracle has no MSIL version, so that you cannot set the target to AnyCPU" http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Oracle-Dataprovider-for-736ad5af

Answer (score 0):

If you do the following, everything works fine
1. Consistently set all your dlls to AnyCPU. 
2. Make sure that the appropriate version of the dll is installed on the machine on which the executable will be run (i.e. 32 bit or 64 bit i.e. same as OS)
3. Ignore compiler warnings that the a 64/32 bit version is being used rather than an MSIL version

The compiled versions can then be used on both 32 and 64 bit as long as the appropriate version of the oracle dll is installed.