# ClickOnce WPF application not running on Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: wpf, windows-7, clickonce, .net-4.5

I have a [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce) (C#, WPF, .NET 4.5) application, it runs and works fine under Windows 7 32-bit. It is compiled as *Any CPU*.

Under Windows 7 64-bit I see the ClickOnce start screen, and then nothing happens (no errors, nothing obvious).

In order to debug, I have copied the EXE file and all relevant DLL files into one directory. I started from there: Again same situation, it runs under Windows 7 32-bit, but nothing happens under Windows 7 64-bit. I have crosschecked with a "clean" Windows 7 32-bit, and it is fine there as well.

.NET 4.5 was / is installed on any machine I have tested with.

How can I overcome / debug the application? What do I need to do make it run under 64-bit?

Event log under APPLICATIONS shows:

```
Faulting application name: MyApp.exe, version: 0.8.1.13, time stamp: 0x50e807c5
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.18015, time stamp: 0x50b8479b
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x0000000000009e5d
Faulting process id: 0x1138
Faulting application start time: 0x01cdeeab375b90da
Faulting application path: B:\Debug\MyApp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 761e9cba-5a9e-11e2-a573-406186f45b4a
```

According to [here](http://davidstechtips.com/2010/06/force-net-application-to-run-in-32-bit-process-on-64-bit-windows/), I could force building as a [Win32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API) application, but is this the right way to go? The application is pretty simple, so I doubt this should be required.

Follow up, about the remote debugging: *[Visual Studio 2012: Can I start a .NET 4.5 application in a remote debugger (and not only attach)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247537)*

The first thing I did was updating the two external (Syncfusion) DLL files to their recent version. It was still crashing, but now I got an additional .NET event in the event viewer. I thought it might be "Syncfusion"-related, but the whole trace does not show any Syncfusion libraries.

```
Application: MyApp.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.TypeInitializationException
Stack:
   at System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer.ListenerExists(System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationEvents)
   at System.Windows.Controls.TabControl.OnSelectionChanged(System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector+SelectionChanger.End()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector+SelectionChanger.SelectJustThisItem(ItemInfo, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.OnSelectedIndexChanged
```

Next thing, in the Visual Studio 2012 build, I checked *Prefer 32-bit*, **this compiled exe runs** on Windows 7 64-bit. So it is partly a success.

[image: Prefer 32-bit]

Comment: Have you checked the event log?

Comment: Good hint, will update, thanks

Comment: Read this SO answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/6245146/520612

Comment: Thanks. Started with VS2012 remote debugging: Problem is that I cannot attach remote debugger, before I can attach to the process the application is gone.

Comment: Have you tried the same thing with a console application that just runs Console.ReadKey()... if that still fails try to change .net version, change the platform(any cpu, x86, x64)...