# Visual Studio 2012: Can I start a .NET 4.5 application in a remote debugger (and not only attach)?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5, remote-debugging

Platform:
  * Visual Studio 2012
  * C# WPF application
  * Visual Studio 2012 remote debugger tools.

My .NET 4.5 application on a 64-bit system [crashes at an very early stage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14246144). I have the Visual Studio 2012 remote debugging running on the (remote) 64-bit system. I can connect from my development computer with Visual Studio 2012, all fine.

My problem is that I need to attach to a process in order to remotely debug. Before I can attach to the process, the application has crashed. Basically I want to set my breakpoints in the very first lines of the `WainWindow.xaml.cs` (it is an WPF application).

Is there a chance to start the application remotely and directly attach to the process?

Comment: This is a thirty-nine dollar problem.  About what it costs to update your dev machine to the 64-bit version of Windows 8.  And what it takes to *actually* support your app on your users machines.  Hurry up, that offer ends soon.