# Unable to start application, KernelBase.dll fault

Tags: c#, windows, kernel

I have a problem to run application on Windows 7/8 x64, but I am able to start on Windows 10 x64. In Visual Studio platform target is set to Any CPU but it not helped me. Application I am building on my dev machine OS: Windows 10 x64

Windows logs

Application error:

```
Faulting application name: Training charts.exe, version: 0.4.3.18, time stamp: 0x55f2b40f
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.18869, time stamp: 0x556366fd
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x000000000000b3dd
Faulting process id: 0x5f0
Faulting application start time: 0x01d0ec8a5e92040f
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Training Charts\Training charts.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 9ccd617f-587d-11e5-ae3d-000c29c8cb67
```

.NET Runtime:

```
Application: Training charts.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.ArgumentException
Stack:
   at MS.Internal.Resources.ResourceManagerWrapper.GetStream(System.String)
   at MS.Internal.AppModel.ResourcePart.EnsureResourceLocationSet()
   at MS.Internal.AppModel.ResourcePart.GetContentTypeCore()
   at System.IO.Packaging.PackagePart.get_ContentType()
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(System.Object, System.Uri)
   at Training_charts.App.InitializeComponent()
   at Training_charts.App.Main()
```

Do you have any ideas how to fix this? App is require .NET 4.5

Comment: Is this relevant : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14711633/my-c-sharp-application-is-returning-0xe0434352-to-windows-task-scheduler-but-it

Comment: I tried to handle AppDomain.CurrentDomain UnhandledException but this not helped to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case there was a problem in AsseblyInfo.cs I had to delete Neutral language line.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, when I deployed my application after updating the .NET framework version, I forgot to deploy the config file. So the old config file was being used that pointed to the wrong runtime.
Specifically this part:

```
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/></startup>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case the combination of EventLog and Linq caused this error on some Windows 10 systems:

```
KERNELBASE.dll, Version: 10.0.17134.319, Timestamp: 0x5ea0e53d
Exception code: 0xc000041d
Error offset: 0x001117d2
ID of erronous process: 0x175c
Path to erronous modul: C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
```

Using Linq to query the whole event log records for just the most recent last one of a specific InstanceId (formerly EventId Z Id) is very unefficient anyway,
I changed the code to use a `EventLogQuery` instead:

```
string queryString = "*[System[Provider[@Name='MyApp'] and (EventID=1 or EventID=2)]]";
EventLogQuery eventsQuery = new EventLogQuery("Application", PathType.LogName, queryString);
eventsQuery.ReverseDirection = true;
eventsQuery.TolerateQueryErrors = true;

try
{
    EventLogReader logReader = new EventLogReader(eventsQuery);
    EventRecord lastLogEntry = logReader.ReadEvent();

}
catch (EventLogNotFoundException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error while reading the event logs");
    return;
}
```