# CreateProcess not able to throw an error when the executable file has an exception thrown at the very beginning

Tags: c#, c++, multithreading, createprocess

There is an executable file and I am throwing an exception at the very beginning of the solution in `program.cs`. When loading this executable file from a different solution using `CreateProcessA()`, I see that the process loads and does not give me an error message. Any idea on how to catch this exception?

```cpp
STARTUPINFOA startupInfo;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
ZeroMemory(&startupInfo, sizeof(startupInfo));
startupInfo.cb = sizeof(startupInfo);
ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

const auto dwCreationFlags = showConsole ? CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE : CREATE_NO_WINDOW;
auto canCreate = true;
if (!CreateProcessA(
    nullptr,                                // LPCWSTR IpApplicationName
    const_cast<LPSTR>(command.c_str()),     // LPSTR IpCommandLine
    nullptr,                                // LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES IpProcessAttributes
    nullptr,                                // LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES IpThreadAttributes
    false,                                  // BOOL bInheritHandles,
    dwCreationFlags,                        // DWORD dwCreationFlags
    nullptr,                                // LPVOID IpEnvironment
    nullptr,                                // LPCWSTR IpCurrentDirectory
    &startupInfo,                           // LPSTARTUPINFOW IpStartupInfo
    &pi                                     // LPPROCESS_INFORMATION IpProcessInformation
))
{
    canCreate = false;
    return Status(WinUtil::GetLastErrorMessage());
}
//canCreate = false;

// Wait until child process exits.
WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, 0);
CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
return Status();
```

I am expecting it to return false and catch the exception.

However, it currently loops for a while, and then throws out a generic message saying that it failed to start. It's not catching the exception I threw at the very beginning of the solution.

Comment: It's not clear at all what you are doing and what you are expecting to happen. Are you saying that you have a C++ program that launches a C# program via CreateProcessA, said C# program throws an exception, and you want to catch that exception in the C++ program?

Comment: C++ program launches a C# program via CreateProcessA. When I throw an exception in C# program at the very beginning, I do not see that exception message.

Comment: C++ isn't going to be able to catch the exceptions thrown by another language. It won't have the slightest clue what they'll look like.  [You could capture and parse the output, though](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42402673/createprocess-and-capture-stdout).

Comment: There's not enough to go on here.  We need two [mre]s, one for the parent task and one for the task that it spawns.  Then, perhaps, someone can help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can't throw exceptions across language boundaries, let alone process boundaries.  A C++ app cannot catch an exception thrown in a separate C# app.

When the C# app throws an exception that is not caught, it will simply terminate itself.  The C++ app that launched it cannot catch that uncaught exception.  The only thing it can do is wait for the C# app to terminate (which you are already doing), and then use [`GetExitCodeProcess()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getexitcodeprocess) to get the exit code, which will be non-zero on an unexpected failure (such as `0xE0434352` for an uncaught managed exception, `0xC0000005` for an access violation, `0xC00000FD` for a stack overflow, etc).

See: [Exit Code When Unhandled Exception Terminates Execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35294313/exit-code-when-unhandled-exception-terminates-execution)