# Windows app crashing - Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.3.9600.17415

Tags: c#, windows, ftp

I have an consoleapp ".exe" which is running as Task Scheduler.
This app usually uploads files to some ftp urls.

The app works fine until some times when someone logs into server they see that the app has crashed and event log shows below message -

```
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.3.9600.17415, time stamp: 0x54504ade
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x00014598
Faulting process id: 0x1920
Faulting application start time: 0x01d233c8ee351c9f
```

Please note that some of the FTP urls configured by client is inaccessible which is handled in code but can too many web exceptions lead to crashing of the app??

How can this be prevented?

Also the scheduler is configured as - All Users than jus admin

Also some may suggest that why this is set as task scheduler and not as windows service. It is done coz sometimes the client wants to upload the file immediately than wait for next hour which i don't think service allows to set.

Comment: Writing an event handler for the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException event, so you can log and diagnose unhandled exceptions, is never really optional.  Helps you to stop guessing, helps us to actually help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My C# application is returning 0xE0434352 to Windows Task Scheduler but it is not crashing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14711633/my-c-sharp-application-is-returning-0xe0434352-to-windows-task-scheduler-but-it)

Comment: I probably have a similar problem. My Windows Service creates some files in differnet Thread (ThreadPool) started from the WinService which sometimes crashes too. There is no obvious reason for.
A single thread uses Crystal Reports library to create a file. In the Windows Service I have `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += ...` that should log the exception, but this never happens.
Q: If a thread crashes, that should be caught by the UnhandledException, is it?
Q: If Crystal Reports library leaves the context of manage code, does it work too? ... or not? - Thanks @HansPassant