# c# process.start don't start process

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to start my application through the Process.Start(), this is done by returning true, but the fact is that the window does not open and there is no process in the Task Manager, no error code returns, after a while the event is an exited returns the exit code -532462766

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var pr = new Process();
        pr.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"Debug\Browser.exe");
        pr.Exited += Pr_Exited;
        var started = pr.Start();
        Console.WriteLine(started.ToString());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void Pr_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var exc = ((Process)sender).ExitCode;
        Console.WriteLine(exc.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide some example code of what you are trying to do.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  It is advised to **not** post an image of your code, but rather to put the text in your post with [proper formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Why is this tagged C (it is not C code) and not C#?

Comment: Have you tried starting other programs; for example, `pr.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("notepad.exe");`? I ran your code , per my modification, and NOTEPAD started; however, I didn't get the ExitCode notification on exit of NOTEPAD

Comment: -532462766 = 0xE0434352 (and 434352 = "CCR"). Here's [an old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14897073/243245) with a suggestion from Hans Passant: add [a handler AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.unhandledexception?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) to catch the exception and work out what's going wrong.