# Unknown Software Exception 0xe0434352

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, runtime-error

While I am trying to launch my application I am getting the following error:
[image]

Checked the app log but no error message.

Is this due to any of framework version or any other dependency?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6244939/how-do-i-fix-a-net-windows-app-crashing-at-startup-with-exception-code-0xe0434

Answer (score 24):

That is a catch all error generated from the CLR. It could mean almost anything.
If you want to find out exactly what the error is, you can check out this webpage: http://ig2600.blogspot.com/2009/07/finding-clr-exceptions-with-visual.html

He explains how to find out what the real errors are. I find it to be quite handy.

Comment: This sure is helpful at the momemnt, but if (when) that site dies, your answer stops being helpful.
Could you take important points from the site and showcase them in your answer here?

Comment: @Squazz Added to my answer since OP is inactive.

Comment: FYI - This catch-all is easy to remember because "434352" is the ASCII for "CCR".  I saw that on MSDN video about debugging CLR.

Answer (score 5):

The top answer is great. Here are the site contents for when it goes down:

**Often exceptions are thrown and caught and you don't see them. You probably know how to debug this in Visual Studio, so let me show you how to do it in cdb.**

**Nothing about an exception, but you're sure it's happening behind the covers -- fire up cdb:**

C:\Program Files\Debugging Tools for Windows (x64)>cdb -pn consoleapplication3.exe

> ModLoad: 000007fe`f7e90000 000007fe`f7eb4000
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.20506\culture.dll
>   (ff8.17a8): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
>   *** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll - ntdll!DbgBreakPoint:
>   00000000`77b7d7b0 cc              int     3 Continue debugging: 0:004>
>   g

Exceptions - lots of them:

> (ff8.16dc): CLR exception - code e0434352 (first chance)
>
> (ff8.16dc): CLR exception - code e0434352 (first chance)
>
> (ff8.16dc): CLR exception - code e0434352 (first chance)
>
> (ff8.16dc): CLR exception - code e0434352 (first chance)
>
> (ff8.16dc): CLR exception - code e0434352 (first chance)
>
> (ff8.16dc): CLR exception - code e0434352 (first chance)
>
> (ff8.1860): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)

Break on CLR exceptions:

> 0:004> sxe clr
>
> 0:004> g
>
> (ff8.16dc): CLR exception - code e0434352 (first chance)
>
> First chance exceptions are reported before any exception handling.
>
> This exception may be expected and handled.
>
> *** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for  C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll -
>   KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x3d: 000007fe`fdb8bb5d 4881c4c8000000  add 
>   rsp,0C8h

Load sos ( in .Net 2/3 use use !loadby sos mscorwks):

> 0:000> !loadby sos clr

View Stack:

> 0:000> !CLRStack
>
> PDB symbol for clr.dll not loaded
>
> OS Thread Id: 0x16dc (0)
>
> Child SP         IP               Call Site
>
> 000000000096e6a8 000007fefdb8bb5d [HelperMethodFrame:
>   000000000096e6a8]
>
> 000000000096e7c0 000007ff00170360
>
> ConsoleApplication3.Program.ThrowAndCatchException()
>
> 000000000096e810 000007ff001701fb
>
> ConsoleApplication3.Program.Main(System.String[])
>
> 000000000096ec90 000007feef474ca4 [GCFrame: 000000000096ec90]

View Exception:

> 0:000> !PrintException
>
> Exception object: 0000000002c88c18
>
> Exception type:   System.NotImplementedException
>
> Message:          The method or operation is not implemented.
>
> InnerException:
>
> StackTrace (generated):
>
> StackTraceString:
>
> HResult: 80004001
>
> 0:000>

Answer (score 2):

On my side I got really scared about this error, since nothing was working on my computer: Settings were closing when trying to open, Windows quick search was not working, Visual Studio was crashing with this error.

After two hours, I observed that I got a new keyboard language near the clock bottom right: it was ENG with . instead of the long name. I switched to the normal one, and boom: it looks like the keyboard language was somehow not supported by Windows: everything was then back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

For the solution of this problem, 5 solutions have been proposed on the site below.
https://thegeekpage.com/how-to-solve-unknown-software-exception-0xe0434352/

I tried 3rd of these and the problem is solved. However, I encountered a problem and the solution was as follows: After downloading "Download Microsoft .NET Framework Repair Tool from Official", an error message appeared stating that there was not enough space. 
I extracted it to the folder with "7zip" software and ran "FixDotNet.exe" in that folder. The problem was resolved after the installation was completed.
[NetFxRepairTool-->FixDotNet.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLRx2.jpg)