# VS2010 unhandled exception while debugging c++ that calls mixed mode that calls c# dll

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2010, mixed

Hi and thanks in advance for your time reading this.

I've got a problem debugging my solution in VS2010. To be more specific, here's the setup:

- everything is coded for Windows 7, 64bit
- the 3rd party EXE (c++) exposes its api over c#
- my plugin (c#) calls into a mixed mode dll
- mixed mode dll calls native c++
- native c++ dll calls a lot of production code already written for other programs (also native c++)
- native c++ dll also calls another mixed mode dll which then calls a c# dll
- everything written and compiled in VS2010

Here's the odd thing:

- when I debug my managed code everything works fine; no exceptions
- when I debug my native code I get random exceptions (0xe0434352) just when c++ calls into the mixed mode dll (which really just is an interface for the code in the c# dll)
- when the exception window (first chance) pops up I hit skip/continue but no further debugging is possible; program execution results are the same though
- the problem disappears if I comment out the call to the mixed mode code

## EDIT:

Posting production code is a bit sensitive. The Exception is just the generic one I mentioned above. The exception window literally says:

- An Exception (first chance) occurred at  in Revit.exe: 0xe0434352: 0xe0434352.
- It's Revit MEP 2013

> KernelBase.dll!000007fefd8f9e5d()
>       [Unten angegebene Rahmen sind möglicherweise nicht korrekt und/oder fehlen, keine Symbole geladen für KernelBase.dll]
>       clr.dll!000007fee65c4e13()
>       clr.dll!000007fee65c597e()
>       000007fe898bad42()
>       000007fe898b65be()
>       000007fe898b646b()
>       000007fe898b6144()
>       000007fe898b5fa3()
>       000007fe898b5d4b()
>       clr.dll!000007fee644f2ee()
>     RevitClient.dll!RvtToMyProg::getPropMappedValue(std::basic_string,std::allocator > & Res="", int Sel=0, DigitalModelMapping & DigiModMap={...}, const CadElem & Elem={...}, std::basic_string,std::allocator > & Prop="NAME")  Zeile 721 + 0x8d Bytes C++
>       RevitClient.dll!RvtToMyProg::addElementAttributes(int Sel=0, const CadElem & CadElem={...}, DigitalModelMapping & DigiModMap={...}, const Descriptor * EntDesc=0x000000003ace72b0, Entity * XDataEnt=0x0000000056ad70a0)  Zeile 630 + 0x75 Bytes    C++
>       RevitClient.dll!RvtToMyProg::dataToMyProg(DigitalModelMapping & DigiModMap={...}, std::set > >,std::less > > >,std::allocator > > > > & Classnames=3, Descriptor & ModDsc={...}, XDataModel & XData={...})  Zeile 575 + 0x46 Bytes C++
>       000007fe898a7aa3()
>       000007fe898a79eb()
>       000007fe898a7837()
>       000007fe898a5aef()
>       000007fe898a5624()
>       clr.dll!000007fee644f2ee()
>       RevitAPIUILink.dll!0000000033c31bfb()
>       RevitAPIUILink.dll!0000000033c326d8()
>       DesktopMFC.dll!00000000007e1843()
>       000007fe898a471e()
>       000007fe898a044f()
>       000007fe8989ff7b()
>       000007fe8989fc3e()
>       000007fe89892e9d()
>       000007fe89892d33()
>       000007fe87d0da2a()
>       000007fe87d0d81b()
>       000007fe89892b1a()
>       000007fe87d0d2e6()
>       000007fe87d0ca76()
>       000007fe87d0955a()
>       000007fe89892880()
>       000007fe898925c9()
>       000007fe8989f382()
>       000007fe89852427()
>       000007fe87d0d2e6()
>       000007fe87d0ca76()
>       000007fe898439be()
>       000007fe87d0d2e6()
>       000007fe87d0ca76()
>       000007fe87d0955a()
>       000007fe896da930()
>       000007fe8943dbb8()
>       000007fe8943cbcb()
>       000007fe8943c84f()
>       000007fe896d3520()
>       000007fe8796a6d8()
>       000007fe8796a261()
>       000007fe873b09ae()
>       000007fe873b087c()
>       000007fe873b06f5()
>       000007fe873b0507()
>       000007fe873afee7()
>       000007fe873acd2e()
>       000007fe873ac383()
>       clr.dll!000007fee644f2ee()
>       user32.dll!0000000077919bd1()
>       user32.dll!00000000779198da()
>       user32.dll!00000000779167c2()
>       mfc100u.dll!CWnd::IsDialogMessageW(tagMSG * lpMsg=0x0000000000000202)  Zeile 198    C++
>       mfc100u.dll!CControlBar::PreTranslateMessage(tagMSG * pMsg=0x000000900abd6714)  Zeile 445 + 0x2c Bytes  C++
>       mfc100u.dll!CWnd::WalkPreTranslateTree(HWND__ * hWndStop=0x000000000922e8a0, tagMSG * pMsg=0x0000000000000002)  Zeile 3311 + 0x10 Bytes C++
>       mfc100u.dll!AfxInternalPreTranslateMessage(tagMSG * pMsg=0x0000000140003070)  Zeile 233 + 0x15 Bytes    C++
>       mfc100u.dll!AfxInternalPumpMessage()  Zeile 178 + 0x12 Bytes    C++
>       mfc100u.dll!CWinThread::Run()  Zeile 634    C++
>       mfc100u.dll!AfxWinMain(HINSTANCE__ * hInstance=0x0000000000000001, HINSTANCE__ * hPrevInstance=0x0000000000000000, wchar_t * lpCmdLine=0x0000000000000000, int nCmdShow=0)  Zeile 47 + 0xd Bytes    C++
>       Revit.exe!00000001400011d6()
>       kernel32.dll!00000000777f652d()
>       ntdll.dll!0000000077a2c521()

- maybe some sample code:

  ```
  c++:
  dostuff()
  {
      //it = std::list::iterator
      std::string = this->MixedMode->GetElementPropertyValue(Sel, it->Name, it->Api);
  }

  mixed mode:

  std::string RevitBridge::GetElementPropertyValue(int Sel, const std::string &Name, const std::string &ApiName)
  {
      String^ sName = gcnew String(Name.c_str());
      String^ sApiName = gcnew String(ApiName.c_str());
      String^ s = RevitUtils::GetElementPropertyValue(Sel, sName, sApiName);
      return std::string(msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(s));
  }

  c#:

  public String GetElementPropertyValue(int Sel, String Name, String ApiName)
  {
      if (Sel < 0)
      {
          return "";
      }

      if (Name.Equals("_ElementID_"))
      {
          return this.GetElementID(Sel);
      }

      BuiltInParameter bip = BuiltInParameter.INVALID;
      try
      {
          bip = (BuiltInParameter)Enum.Parse(typeof(BuiltInParameter), ApiName);
      }
      catch (Exception) {}

      if (ApiName.Equals("INVALID") || BuiltInParameter.INVALID == bip)
      {
          return this.GetElemParamValueAsString_ByName(iters[Sel].Current, Name);
      }

      return this.GetElemParamValueAsString(iters[Sel].Current, bip);
  }
  ```

I'd be glad for any kind of advice pointing me in the right direction.

Thanks,
Kornel

Comment: Your question is way to broad as it stands, do you have any code sample/call stack/exception *name*?

Comment: If you search for 0xe0434352 you might find an answer e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15065755/unknown-software-exception-0xe0434352

Comment: The managed code threw an exception, nothing unusual about that.