# Visual Studio 2019 wont start - could not start visual studio due to an error. System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Yesterday after work, I closed Visual studio. Since then I am unable to start it again.
I am using Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise v16.8.3.
I tried

- Changing the config file.
- Deleting VisualStudio AppData
- Repairing VS from VS installer
- Reinstalling VS
- Repairing .Net Framework
- Running VS in Safe Mode

I am always getting the same results.
I get a dialog with title: Microsoft Visual Studio
and text: Could not start visual studio due to an error. System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException:Configuration system failed to initialize
InnerException -
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException:unrecognized configuration section startup.
(C:\Users\tomig\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_ed2a0239\devenv.exe.config line 13)

After clicking Ok, There is one more dialog with title: Hidden Window:devenv.exe - Application Error
And text: The exception unknown software exception (0x0434352) occured in the application at location 0x00000000775546D2.

Can someone help me to make Visual Studio work again?[System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqBav.png)
[Hidden Window:devenv.exe - Application Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UL4Nv.png)

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2"/>
</startup>
```

[Full devenv.exe.config](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqYeDnV6K6FohopqJQ8ZI1sLKCYwzQ?e=J6NDcb)

Comment: Have you looked in the file "C:\Users\tomig\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_ed2a0239\devenv.exe.config" at line 13 and earlier to see if there is an obvious problem? If there isn't a correctable problem, then you could rename that file with ".bak" as the extension and see if VS will start.

Comment: I have edited my question, added 13,14,15 lines of config file as well as link to full file. I see no problems there. I tried to comment this lines out, only to be replaced with problem further down the config file.

Comment: You could look up the error number, e.g. [Unknown Software Exception 0xe0434352](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15065755/unknown-software-exception-0xe0434352).