# How to fix 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' newer version of kernelbase.dll

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, kernel-module

I have a program that has been running for quite some time, until the latest release of KERNELBASE.dll (10.0.17134.XXX) appeared on some PC's that are running Windows 10.

I am using Visual Studio 2017 Version 15.5.7, programming in C#. PC's with earlier versions of KERNELBASE.dll (i.e. 10.0.14393.XXXX) have no problems running the program.

The program fails in the MainForm_v2.Designer.cs code, when the         private void InitializeComponent() process is called. This contains a multitude of Windows initialization components; here is an excerpt:

```
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(MainForm_v2));
            this.fileToolStripMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
            this.newProjectToolStripMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
            this.createBlankProjectToolStripMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
```

The error message I am receiving is:

```
Error 5/21/2019 3:51:23 PM Application Error 1000 (100)

Log Name: Application
Source: Application Error
Date: 5/21/2019 3:51:23 PM
Event ID: 1000
Task Category: (100)
Level: Error
Keywords: Classic
User: N/A
Computer: 078
Description:
Faulting application name: WW2019.exe, version: 2019.2.1.0, time stamp: 0x5ce4394b
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.17134.556, time stamp: 0xb9f4a0f1
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x000000000003a388
Faulting process id: 0x676c
Faulting application start time: 0x01d51016f23df4e2
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\WW\WW\WW2019.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 1d4eb31c-7ccf-4bd6-ab98-0bd381db3534
Faulting package full name:
Faulting package-relative application ID:
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
<System>
<Provider Name="Application Error" />
<EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID>
<Level>2</Level>
<Task>100</Task>
<Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2019-05-21T20:51:23.067292600Z" />
<EventRecordID>22465</EventRecordID>
<Channel>Application</Channel>
<Computer>078</Computer>
<Security />
</System>
<EventData>
<Data>WW2019.exe</Data>
<Data>2019.2.1.0</Data>
<Data>5ce4394b</Data>
<Data>KERNELBASE.dll</Data>
<Data>10.0.17134.556</Data>
<Data>b9f4a0f1</Data>
<Data>e0434352</Data>
<Data>000000000003a388</Data>
<Data>676c</Data>
<Data>01d51016f23df4e2</Data>
<Data>C:\Program Files (x86)\WW\WW\WW2019.exe</Data>
<Data>C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll</Data>
<Data>1d4eb31c-7ccf-4bd6-ab98-0bd381db3534</Data>
<Data>
</Data>
<Data>
</Data>
</EventData>
</Event>
```

Comment: It has nothing whatsoever to do with kernelbase.dll.  Writing an event handler for the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException event so you won't let it get this far without a good exception message is never really optional.

Comment: [How do I fix a .NET windows application crashing at startup with Exception code: 0xE0434352?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6244939/7444103). [Finding CLR exceptions without visual studio](http://ig2600.blogspot.com/2009/07/finding-clr-exceptions-with-visual.html).

Comment: @Hans I inherited this program, with over 3 million lines of code, along with several other legacy programs. I totally understand the need of good exception messages.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible the VC redistributable is not up to date.  DLL hell has not completely gone away with .NET, as we all are aware of, and down deep there are a set of DLLs that sometimes are linked to in an older version via VS and aren't necessarily present on a late version OS. It's easy enough to fix, usually.  Visit this page for some info on it:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/determining-which-dlls-to-redistribute?view=vs-2019

The location to visit for the downloads is here:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads

This is not guaranteed to fix the problem, but in several scenarios similar to the one described here, updating the redistributables solved the problem for me.

HTH,

CT