# Command Prompt/PowerShell Closing Automatically with Error -532462766/-1 in Visual Studio Code

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, terminal, command, command-prompt

Description:
I am encountering an issue with both Command Prompt and PowerShell in Visual Studio Code. Whenever I attempt to open either the Command Prompt or PowerShell terminal within Visual Studio Code, the terminal window closes automatically after a few seconds, and I receive an error message.

For PowerShell, the error message reads:
"The terminal process 'C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe' terminated with exit code: -532462766."

And for Command Prompt, the error message is:
"The terminal process 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe' terminated with exit code: -1."

This problem persists regardless of whether I access the terminal through Visual Studio Code or open it separately. I have tried restarting Visual Studio Code, reinstalling both Visual Studio Code and PowerShell, and ensuring that all software is up to date, but the issue remains unresolved.

Any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I have tried restarting Visual Studio Code, reinstalling both Visual Studio Code and PowerShell, and ensuring that all software is up to date, but the issue remains unresolved.

Comment: The exit code is super generic - it basically means the .NET runtime encountered _some exception_. Check the Application channel in Event Viewer, you might see more detailed errors/stack trace

Comment: There might be some clues in https://stackoverflow.com/q/6244939/447901. `0xE0434352 -eq -532462766` Have you tried uninstalling and installing VS Code? Since this question is not about source code, some may consider it off-topic for SO.

Comment: I would run with cmd.exe/K which will keep window open after failure so you can see where code is failing.  I think error 0xE0434352 is failure for File Not Found.

Comment: i tried but didn't work i noticed  that when pc is not connected to internet it doesn't close but when connected it closes