# Implementing Oracle.Web.dll, Oracle.DataAccess.dll 64-bit failed on Windows Server 2008 with IIS 7.5 32-bit disabled

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, oracle11g, iis-7.5, 32bit-64bit, windows-server-2008-r2

After successfully testing my MVC4 programs using this environment

[image: Oracle 32-bit working]

I tried to publish it to 64-bit Windows 2008 Server with the IIS that disallows 32 bit apps, then I start getting stuck with the exception : the referenced dll's dependencies cannot be found!

I tried every advice the internet can give me including modifying web.config to reflect their dlls' on deploy-to server win 2008 using global cache cmd's on the prompt!

Yet nothing works. 32-bit is working but 64-bit is flat broke!

[image: Oracle x64 flat broke]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I stopped messing around the web.config. Then, I re-installed Oracle 11g 64 on my Windows 2008 server. Finally I placed ODAC on top of 11gx64's installation. The key to success is locating the correct ODAC to match the version of Oracle you have on your system.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html

To VERIFY you have the right ODAC installed correctly over oracle 11 g you have to look into [asp.net] and [ODP.net] directories to make sure they BOTH have 2.x's and 4's dirs in each bin and their presence in global cache 64.

[image: installOracle64withODAC]

[image: GAC_64 Assembly view for Oracle.Dataaccess and Oracle.Web]

Ater solving the ODAC installation problem, I start experimenting with oracle client dll's. I copied the Oracle.DataAccess.dll(64-bit) from bin [2.x] to my app's compiled bin only to watch my program still crashed with the same complaint that it cannot find the dependent DLL's. Then I copied the Oracle.DataAccess.dll from bin [4], then everything WORKS fine!!

Now the remaining question is why 4.112.4 not found in register cache GAC_64 is working great but the set of dll's registered in GAC_64 broke the program?  Can't help not being confused.

See the resulting view of the working dlls ==>

[image: installOracle64 with working dll]

If you acquire all those screens I show in this case, your MVC4 apps should fly high with Oracle 11 g 64-bit client!  Good luck! I'll share mine with you!

Comment: I had the same problem on a 2008 R2 server. None of the other advice online helped. Grabbing the 64 bit Oracle.DataAccess.dll file from the Oracle website did help it seems.

Comment: However while it seems to connect now I get an error message?   "the type initializer for 'oracle.dataaccess.client.oracleconnection' threw an exception"

Comment: For some reason all my inserted .jpg's have disappeared which are crucial to the answer. I have re-edited the answer putting back the important pictures in.  Hope you can see them clear enough to answer your question.